I have created Custom Woocommerce Payment Plugin but i am not getting anything on checkout page
I have created a custom payment WooCommerce plugin. Once I activate my plugin its showing and accepting data in WooCommerce->Settings->Payments. But its not showing that plugin as payment gateway on checkout page.
When i go to settings->payment page it shows me my payment method and also accept my keys etc. But when i save details and move to checkout page its not showing any option their
I am waiting for a quick response and answer.
Please help me with it.

<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: Liberty Dollar Payment Gateway
 * Plugin URI: https://libertydollar.nl
 * Description: Introducing the Liberty Dollar Payment Gateway for WordPress, the ultimate solution for users looking to accept and make payments using Liberty Dollar balances directly on their WordPress websites.
 * Author: Liberty Dollar Team
 * Author URI: https://libertydollar.nl
 * Version: 0.1.2
 */

add_action('plugins_loaded', 'liberty_init_class');

function liberty_init_class() {
    // Check if WooCommerce is active
    if ( ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) ) {
        // If WooCommerce is not active, bail out
        return;
    }

    // Continue if WooCommerce is active

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'liberty_add_gateway_class' );
    function liberty_add_gateway_class( $gateways ) {
        $gateways[] = 'WC_Liberty_Gateway';
        return $gateways;
    }

    class WC_Liberty_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
        
        public $testmode;
        public $private_key;
        public $publishable_key;
        
        public function __construct() {
            $this->id                 = 'libertydollar';
            $this->icon               = 'https://www.libertydollar.nl/static/media/ldfa-round-logo.76072dece7b030176311.png'; 
            $this->has_fields         = false; 
            $this->method_title       = 'Liberty Dollar Payment Gateway';
            $this->method_description = 'Description of Liberty Dollar payment gateway'; 

            $this->init_form_fields();
            $this->init_settings();

            $this->title              = $this->get_option( 'title' );
            $this->description        = $this->get_option( 'description' );
            $this->enabled            = $this->get_option( 'enabled' );
            $this->testmode           = 'yes' === $this->get_option( 'testmode' );
            $this->private_key        = $this->testmode ? $this->get_option( 'test_private_key' ) : $this->get_option( 'private_key' );
            $this->publishable_key    = $this->testmode ? $this->get_option( 'test_publishable_key' ) : $this->get_option( 'publishable_key' );

            add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'thankyou_page' ) );
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', array( $this, 'change_payment_complete_order_status' ), 10, 3 );

            add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_submit', array( $this, 'payment_fields' ) );
        }

        public function init_form_fields(){
            $this->form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Enable/Disable',
                    'label'       => 'Enable Liberty Dollar Payment Gateway',
                    'type'        => 'checkbox',
                    'description' => '',
                    'default'     => 'no'
                ),
                'title' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Title',
                    'type'        => 'text',
                    'description' => 'This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.',
                    'default'     => 'Liberty Dollar Payment Gateway',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
                'description' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Description',
                    'type'        => 'textarea',
                    'description' => 'This controls the description which the user sees during checkout.',
                    'default'     => 'Pay with Liberty Dollar Wallet.',
                ),
                'testmode' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Test mode',
                    'label'       => 'Enable Test Mode',
                    'type'        => 'checkbox',
                    'description' => 'Place the payment gateway in test mode using test API keys.',
                    'default'     => 'yes',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
                'test_publishable_key' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Test Publishable Key',
                    'type'        => 'text'
                ),
                'test_private_key' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Test Private Key',
                    'type'        => 'password',
                ),
                'publishable_key' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Live Publishable Key',
                    'type'        => 'text'
                ),
                'private_key' => array(
                    'title'       => 'Live Private Key',
                    'type'        => 'password'
                    )
            );
        }

        public function payment_fields() {
            echo '<div id="custom-payment-form">Pay Via LDFA</div>';
        }

    }
}



Because you are using new Checkout Block, instead of classic Checkout (legacy shortcode)… Here is a tutorial to make a custom payment method for Checkout Block and this related thread
